# How to calculate value of an element based on clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, cart

I need to calculate remaining money based on what item, inside the cart, is selected.

For example: I have 3 items in my cart, and I select the one that costs `100$`, and previously I have added that I have `300$`.

I have elements with `id="price"` and `id="total"`, and I want to place inside `id="remaining"`, the difference between `total` and `price`, based on the `id` of the element that I clicked, to add to cart.

I think, that it could be done using **jquery**, but I am new at this, so any help would be great.

```
<div class="items">
<div id="first">
<p>First Product</p>
<p class="price">100$</p>
<button id="btn1">Add to cart</button>
</div>

<div id="second">
<p>Second Product</p>
<p class="price">150$</p>
<button id="btn2">Add to cart</button>
</div>

<div id="third">
<p>Third Product</p>
<p class="price">200$</p>
<button id="btn3">Add to cart</button>
</div>
</div>

<p>Available money</p>
<p class="total">300$</p>

<p>Remaining money</p>
<p class="remaining"> </p>
```

Comment: do you have any code you've already tried?

Comment: No, because I don't know how to do this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [tour] and the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post your HTML and whatever script you have so far

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should give the "total" and "remaining" class paragraph tags unique ids. Then get all the prices and add them together with [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
var itemSum = 0;
$(".price").each(function() {
    itemSum += $(this).html(); //you may have to parse this to an integer value
});
```

except you will have to get rid of the $ in your `p` tags, something like `$<p class="price">100</p>` will be better. Now if you give your total and remaining `p` tags ids such as "total" and "remaining", just get the "total" value in the same way as above, and put the difference in "remaining", with the `html()` function again:

```
$("#remaining").html(/*calculate remaining, like total - itemSum*/);
```